# WooCommerce trigger URL after order complete

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

Is it possible to trigger an URL after an order is completed. It is not an URL the customer should be send to but in the back-end this URL should be visited so an API is called. I am a bit new to this so dont know if this is the right way. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be great.

I got this URL that should be triggered filled with variables I should get after completing the order:

https:///v1/invite/externalhash=XXX&location_id=XXX&tenantId=XX&invite_email=XXX&delay=X&first_name=XXX&last_name=XXX&language=XX&ref_code=XXXX

- invite_email -> This should be the e-mail the order is placed with
- first_name -> This should be the name the order is placed with
- last_name -> This should be the Last name the order is placed with
- language -> This should be the language code (lowercase) of the shipping country the order is shipped to

I know this is a lot but how should I do this?

**EDIT**
Ok I found a way to do this with CURL but how can I excute below code without opening the URL in the browser?

```
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
```

I just want to excute the URL but dont want to open it in my browser. Just a quick call and that's it.

Is this possible with CURL?

**Edit 2.0.1**

I changes my function with order status complete. I got this almost working but for some reason when using a "dynamic" url the URL is not triggered.

I also added an echo alert in javascript and this alert is passing the exact good dynamic URL so that is working as it shoud. Below the function with the alert:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_process_order');
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    // Get the order info
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if($order->get_billing_country() == "NL"){
    // create a new cURL resourc
        $ch = curl_init();
        $voornaam = $order->get_billing_first_name();
        $achternaam = $order->get_billing_last_name();
        $email = $order->get_billing_email();

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("https://klantenvertellen.nl/v1/invite/external?hash=0926-4adb-a39e-d04110d1e445&location_id=104679&tenantId=99&invite_email='.$email.'&delay=1&first_name='.$voornaam.'&last_name='.$achternaam.'&language=nl");</script>';
        // set URL and other appropriate options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://klantenvertellen.nl/v1/invite/external?hash=0926-4adb-a39e-d04110d1e445&location_id=10479&tenantId=99&invite_email='.$email.'&delay=1&first_name='.$voornaam.'&last_name='.$achternaam.'&language=nl');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // grab URL and pass it to the browser
        curl_exec($ch);
        // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

When I use this the URL is not triggered. But the Alert URL is like this:
https://klantenvertellen.nl/v1/invite/external?hash=0926-4adb-a39e-d04110d1e445&location_id=104679&tenantId=99&invite_email=test@email.com&delay=1&first_name=my first name&last_name=my lastname&language=nl

Exactly as it shoud but for some reason the CURL function is not triggered. When I add the URL like this in the function:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://klantenvertellen.nl/v1/invite/external?hash=0926-4adb-a39e-d04110d1e445&location_id=104679&tenantId=99&invite_email=test@email.com&delay=1&first_name=my first name&last_name=my lastname&language=nl');
```

The URL is triggered. So what am I doing wrong that when adding the URL manualy it is working and when working with variables it aint working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly got it working with this function inside my functions.php when an order is completed.

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'custom_process_order');
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    // Get the order info
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    if($order->get_billing_country() == "NL"){
    // create a new cURL resourc
        $ch = curl_init();
        $voornaam = $order->get_billing_first_name();
            $voornaam_new = str_replace(' ', '%20', $voornaam);
        $achternaam = $order->get_billing_last_name();
            $achternaam_new = str_replace(' ', '%20', $achternaam);
        $email = $order->get_billing_email();

        // set URL and other appropriate options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://klantenvertellen.nl/v1/invite/external?hash=0926-4adb-a39e-d04110d1e445&location_id=104679&tenantId=99&invite_email='.$email.'&delay=1&first_name='.$voornaam_new.'&last_name='.$achternaam_new.'&language=nl');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // grab URL and pass it to the browser
        curl_exec($ch);
        // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
        curl_close($ch);
    }
}
```

I also added a if statement because I only want to trigger it when a customer orderd from the Netherlands. The problem was with the spaces in the firstname or last name so I replaced them with %20 with a str_replace.

Hope this can help other that want to do this.

Comment: Hi, im facinh the samething or it seems like, i got a page.php and need to alert that page when there is a new order,  after using ur script. How can i recieve the data that was send on page.php

Answer (score 3):

You could use the action `woocommerce_payment_complete` like so:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'custom_process_order', 10, 1);
function custom_process_order($order_id) {
    // Get the order info
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Your custom logic here, for instance calling the url with curl
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    // ...
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response, this got me in the right direction. Only I dont want to open in the link in the browser. I edited my question, how can I do this with CURL without opening the url in browser?

Comment: @user2812779 well yes it is possible, try with CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER: `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);` I updated my answer.

Comment: thank you for the response. I almost got it working but for some reason in the functions.php inside a function it aint working. You got an idea why?

Comment: @user2812779 without seeing the functions.php file, difficult to say! But you can try the following: drop your function and the action in a file named `woo-order-complete-actions.php` within the folder `wp-content/mu-plugins`. You can create this folder if it doesn't exist. It is for custom "must use plugins" and are automatically activated. Less messy than using the `functions.php` file that is related to your theme, in my opinion. See [WordPress doc on mu plugins](https://wordpress.org/support/article/must-use-plugins/)

Comment: thanks a lot again for your answer, I changed my function to order complete so I can check it better. I added an Alert so I can check if my dynamic URL is good and it is. But when using it in the function it is not working. I edited my answer. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: I found the problem, it has to do with spaces in the first name or last name... Have to find a workaround for it.